# CodeIgniter Login with enter key

Tags: php, ajax, forms, codeigniter, submit

have this in my login form :

```
<div class="middle-box loginscreen  animated fadeInDown">
<div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="logo-name"><?= $this->lang->line('GGG')?></h1>
    </div>
    <h3><?= $this->lang->line('GGG')?></h3>
    <form class="m-t" role="form" action="welcome/check_user" id="check_user" method="POST">
        <div id="save_result"></div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label" for="username"><?= $this->lang->line('Username')?><sup class="mandatory">*</sup></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control required email" placeholder="<?= $this->lang->line('Username')?>" name="username" id="username" maxlength="50">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label" for="password"><?= $this->lang->line('Password')?><sup class="mandatory">*</sup></label>
            <input type="password" id="btn" class="form-control required" placeholder="<?= $this->lang->line('Password')?>" name="password" id="password">
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="submit_form('#check_user')" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b"><?= $this->lang->line('Login')?></button>
```

need to get enter button to submit and it wont.

Comment: What happen? Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Because you are using `onclick`. Use `onsubmit`

Answer (score 0):

Change button type to `submit` instead of `button` - browsers would the submit the form on enter

```
<button type="submit" onclick="submit_form('#check_user')" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b"><?= $this->lang->line('Login')?></button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but it does not work. It does let me in with enter key but the #check_user function then fails and the site does not load.

Comment: can you paste what the submit_form function looks like. Form submission can be done programmatically in javascript.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. Here is the submit_form function.

    function submit_form(form_selector,target)
    {
    target= target || "#save_result";
    
    $(target).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
    change_validation_position(form_selector);
        
    $(form_selector).ajaxSubmit({
        beforeSubmit:function(arr,$form){
            if ($($form).valid()==true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            $(target).html('');
            return false;
        },
        target:target
    }); 
}

Comment: I can see that you are using $($form) while $form itself is sufficient. My guess is that the validation is failing and your "return false"  is preventing the form from being submitted.